# creating Sites using java

Tags: java, sites

i developed one application used to create google sites by referring the [developer guide](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/sites/SitesService.html) in which i don't know what are the three parameters in this is particular line

`SitesService client = new SitesService("yourCo-yourAppName-v1")`.

This is my problem. help me

Comment: There are two constructors for SiteService that take three arguments - which one don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one parameter in your example, it is the application name.

What you have in your example is an example of an application name composed from a company name (yourCo) a name for the application (yourAppName) and a version for your application (v1).

Does this help you ?